# Angular 7 and Child Routes

Tags: angular

I am running into the issue of clean separation of Routes based on Form and Menu. I have for example a Menu Item called Setup which has a Bucket and Tags sub Item. Bucket and Tags are used all over my app to categorize different Items.  So as i started with Bucket i stuck the Setup Child Route into a bucket.module

```
 path: 'Setup',
 loadChildren: 'app/views/buckets/bucket.module#BucketModule'
```

now as i am expanding to at the Tags to it i wonder what would be the best approach ? 
Currently my bucket.module imports my bucket-routing.module where i define the child route

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'Buckets',
    component: BucketGridComponent,
    data: { displayName: 'Bucket List' },
  },
];
```

So i could simply add the Tag route in this route module and it would do the trick but that would be mixing stuff. So what would be the right way to handle this ? Group the routes in a file based on the menu in this case create a Setup route Module or is there a way to load multiple ChildRoutes under same Parent in this case Setup ?

Comment: I would create a setup module with its own separate routing with lazy routes to both buckets and tags.  Something like this. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qxpj7o

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show more details in same page then use Child Route Array. Here is working demo link you can use like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hxlarm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts

Click on ProductList main menu that loads lazy module with child route array.